# subviews moving each other - ios

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

In my application I have a note Object that contains UITextView:

```
class Note: UIView, UITextViewDelegate {

    var textEditor : UITextView!

    override init(frame: CGRect)
    {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        textEditor = UITextView(frame: frame)
        textEditor.frame.origin.x = 0
        textEditor.frame.origin.y = 0
        self.addSubview(textEditor)
    }
```

In my controller I add the Note object and in addition I add UIImageView.
From some reason, when I the UIImageView the UITextView which is inside the Note object moves down.

This is how it looks like with this code:

```
// the Note object
self.view.addSubview(note)

// the UIImageView
twitterImage.center = CGPoint(x: self.view.center.x, y: 50.0)
self.view.addSubview(twitterImage)
```

[image]

When I first add the image and then the Note it looks good:

```
// the UIImageView
twitterImage.center = CGPoint(x: self.view.center.x, y: 50.0)
self.view.addSubview(twitterImage)

// the Note object
self.view.addSubview(note)
```

[image]

The thing is that I need the image to be above the note.

Why is the textview pushed down when I add the image above him? How can I fix this?

Comment: May be size of image is large and cover area of textview.do one thing add image view before textview and do beingsubviewtofront to imageview

Comment: I checked it an it's not the case. I also tried the bringsubviewtofront and it didn't help. When the image view is above the textview it moves it down...

Comment: How much down? Seems to be below the too layout guide. Would you by any chance use NSLayoutConstraint and AutoLayout? If not, why?